# Ranger file manager - getting it to open archive files with custom script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, filemanager

I've acquired a custom bash script which extracts all archive files and waits for input. Below:

```
    #!/bin/bash

GET="."

SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"

err() {
    printf >&2 "$SCRIPTNAME: $*\n"
    exit 1
}

ARC="$1"
[[ -f $ARC ]] || err $"'$ARC' does not exist"
ARC="$(readlink -f "$ARC")"

read -p "Extract to [default: $DEFAULT_TARGET]: " TARGET
[[ -z $TARGET ]] &&\
    TARGET="$DEFAULT_TARGET"
[[ -d $TARGET ]] || err $"Directory '$TARGET' does not exist"
[[ -w $TARGET ]] || err $"Permission denied: '$TARGET' is not writable"

cd "$TARGET"
case "$ARC" in
    *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tar.gz)    tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$ARC"     ;;
    *.rar)       unrar e "$ARC"     ;;
    *.gz)        gunzip "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tar)       tar xf "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tbz2)      tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tgz)       tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.zip)       unzip "$ARC"       ;;
    *.Z)         uncompress "$ARC"  ;;
    *.7z)        7z x "$ARC"        ;;
    *)           echo "'$ARC' cannot be extracted by $SCRIPTNAME" ;;
esac
```

I am using the Ranger FM. I am trying to get it to use the script /usr/bin/extract.sh to open all archive files. Running the script from a terminal is no problem, but as I'm trying to use it in Ranger, I get:

/usr/bin/extract.sh - label is undefined.

I've added the following to my .config/ranger/rifle.conf:

label extract, ext 7z|ace|ar|arc|bz2?|cab|cpio|cpt|deb|dgc|dmg|gz,  = /usr/bin/extract.sh -- "$@"

Yet, it is not working. What've I done wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it. For anyone interested, it was a combination of simple syntax error and having to:

1. Put the script, named extract.sh, in /bin/extract (without .sh)
2. Add an alias as such to .zshrc: alias extract="/bin/extract"
3. Have the following lines in .config/ranger/rifle.conf (the syntax error :):

   ext 7z|ace|ar|arc|bz2?|cab|cpio|cpt|deb|dgc|dmg|gz, has aunpack  = extract "$@"

   ext iso|jar|msi|pkg|rar|shar|tar|tgz|xar|xpi|xz|zip,  has tar, '   flag f = extract "$@"

   label extract, ext 7z|ace|ar|arc|bz2?|cab|cpio|cpt|deb|dgc|dmg|gz,  = /bin/extract

Comment: there is now a built in alias "ext" that seems to do this.